# Автозаполнение input с позможностью поиска по select?

Tags: javascript, php

Проблема такая. Выпадающий список берет из БД необходимые поля, и работает возможность авто заполнения input только без функции поиска по select.

```
 echo  '<option value='.$r.'"klin":"'.$result['klin'].'","tel":"'.$result['tel'].'","email":"'.$result['email'].'","adr":"'.$result['adr'].'"'.$rn.'>'.$result['klin'].'</option>';
```

Соответственно при выборе из списка input поля с id: klin, tel, email и т.п. заполняются с возможностью правки.

Подскажите как можно добавить поиск по select сохраним возможность подстановки в другие input. Были попытки и использовать  и  onkeyup="autocomplet()". Не выходит..
Спасибо!
Часть кода:

```html
<span class="input-group-addon">Выбор Контрагента</span>
<select type="text" id="employees" class="form-control select" onkeyup="autocomplet()" autocomplete="off" />
<option>Выбрать</option>
<?php
     if($_GET['klins']){
    $getklin = $_GET['klins'];
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `viezd_events` WHERE klin LIKE '%$getklin%' GROUP BY adr", $link);  
    while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
    $r="'{";
    $rn="}'";
     echo  '<option value='.$r.'"klin":"'.$result['klin'].'","tel":"'.$result['tel'].'","adr":"'.$result['adr'].'"'.$rn.'>'.$result['klin'].' - <i>'.$result['adr'].'</i> тел: '.$result['tel'].'</option>';
    }
    }else
    {
      $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `viezd_events` WHERE klin LIKE '%$getklin%' GROUP BY adr", $link);  
    while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
    $r="'{";
    $rn="}'";
     echo  '<option value='.$r.'"klin":"'.$result['klin'].'","tel":"'.$result['tel'].'","email":"'.$result['email'].'","adr":"'.$result['adr'].'"'.$rn.'>'.$result['klin'].'</option>';
    }  
    }
    ?>

  </select>


  <label>ФИО:</label>

  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
      <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
    </div>
    <input name="fio" id="fio" type="text" class="form-control">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Неудача использования

> onkeyup="autocomplet()"

обусловлена тем, что у вас не определена функция autocomplet(). Это должен быть JS код, который после каждого нажатия клавиши отправляет запрос на сервер, получает данные и отображает эти данные соответствующим образом.